# Return query with missing/different data only

Tags: php, mysql, select

i have a form where you can select category and will return products that are in this category

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT id, name FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "shared_products_product WHERE category = '" . (int)$id . "' AND status != 2");
```

Result

```
Array
(
[0] => Test 1
[1] => Test 2
[2] => Test 3
)
```

Than you can select only Test 1 and Test 2 to insert in different table

```
$this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "shared_products_view SET product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "', shared_product_id = '" . (int)$shared_product_id . "', category_id = '" . (int)$cat_id . "'");
```

When i run 1st query how will i get result that still not inserted into shared_products_view for current category_id ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to join table and check if value is already existing

Like this

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT `spp`.id, `spp`.name 
FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "shared_products_product `spp`
LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "shared_products_view `spv` ON `spp`.`id`=`spv`.shared_product_id 
WHERE category = '" . (int)$id . "' AND status != 2 AND `spv`.shared_product_id IS NULL");
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run your second query, the INSERT, the row will be added, unless you have an error. One thing that comes to mind is you seem to insert integers as strings.

It is better to use PDO and bindValue() and explicitly state it is an integer.

If I understand you right, you want to know if the INSERT succeeded. (Is that correct?)

In that case check the result of your command $this->db->query("INSERT ...").

You didn't mention what database handle $this->db is, but I expect it will return false on failure.

I highly recommend you study this hands-on guide first before proceeding:

https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

Comment: is not what im looking for @Oleksandr Pobuta submit right answer